# Connecting using public key with Paramiko from AWS lambda to non AWS server

Tags: python, ssh, aws-lambda, paramiko

I am trying to use Paramiko to transfer a file from AWS Lambda to on-prem host using SSH authentication.

I have been given the public key of the on prem host. Is it possible to connect using public key as everywhere while searching Paramiko methods mentions private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two keys possibly involved when connecting to an SSH server:

1. Private key (or actually whole key pair) that you use to authenticate to the server.
2. Server's public key that you should use to verify the identity of the SSH server. This part is often omitted. In many examples you find on the Internet, you won't see it (in Paramiko, it's bypassed by `AutoAddPolicy`). That that is a security flaw.

See my article [Understanding SSH key pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys).

So you might have been given 2. But then you still need 1. (or a password) to authenticate to the server. Hard to tell, without more details.